# Variance when creating interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, nullable, covariance

```
  public interface SomeInterfaceName<out T> where T : struct
  {
    T? SomePropertyName { get; }
  }
```

The error I get is:

> error CS1961: Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'SomeInterfaceName.SomePropertyName'. 'T' is covariant.

I do not *need* this to be Covariant. I could as well delete the out keyword. But then Resharper is suggesting I could use Covariance and I agree, I don't see why I could not. I'm only using T as return value. Or is it because Nullable<> does not support it?

Can anybody explain the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pointless to make a type parameter with a `struct` constraint covariant. Generic variance isn't supported for value type type arguments at all - so for example, there's no conversion from `IEnumerable<int>` to either `IEnumerable<long>` or `IEnumerable<object>` even though there are conversions from `int` to both `long` and `object`.

The problem you're actually running into is that `Nullable<T>` isn't covariant, but you're trying to use `T` in a property of type `Nullable<T>`. That's what's causing the error.

Personally I think it would be better if type parameters with `struct` constraints couldn't be declared to be covariant or contravariant (given that it won't be useful) but that in itself isn't prohibited.